# In-app billing subscription issue

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, subscription

I have subscriptions working in my app but I am getting a random error, once in a while. I'm querying inventory as follows:

```
mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
```

The IabResult that comes back is Failure with the following message:

> android iabResult: Error refreshing inventory
>   (querying prices of subscriptions).
>   (response: 6:Error)

It works approximately 8 out of 10 times, but fails the other two times.  I don't want to fly in that airplane. Is this just the way it is or can something be done about it?

Comment: can you post some of your code snippet to find you missed something there!

Answer (score 0):

Like most questions on this forum, I'll answer my own question again.

This happens when, for whatever reason, local Google Play code can't get to the server.  The answer is that it has to be tolerated.

I'm going to take note if a phone ever had a subscription and when the failure occurs, I'll give the user the benefit of the doubt if a subscription ever was in effect.